# how to connect to outside world from container in Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have a Kubernetes cluster and I want to connect to outside world from container in Kubernetes

For example, I have a database on remote server whose IP address is 10.1.1.111 and I can connect to it from my laptop.

Now I deploy my application in Kubernetes cluster on my laptop, the simplified structure is like:

```
      ------------------------------------------------------
     |   laptop                                             |
     |     ---------------- (Kubernetes) --------------     |
     |    |                                            |    |
     |    |            ------ deployment ------        |    |
     |    |           |  ------- pod --------  |       |    |       ---(remote server)---
     |    |           | |  -- contaniner --  | |       |    |      | (http://10.1.1.111) |
     |    |           | | |                | | |       |    |      |                     | 
user ----- ingress ---  | |      App       | | |-------------------       Database       |
     |    |           | | |________________| | |       |    |      |                     |
     |    |           |  ____________________  |       |    |      |_____________________|
     |    |            ________________________        |    |
     |    |____________________________________________|    |
      _______________________________________________________
```

If from my laptop, I can connect to remote server,

```
      ------------------------------------------------------
     |   laptop * ----------------------------------------------------------
     |     ---------------- (kubernete) ----------------    |               | 
     |    |                                            |    |               |  connect ok !
     |    |            ------ deployment ------        |    |               |
     |    |           |  ------- pod --------  |       |    |       ---(remote server)---
     |    |           | |  -- contaniner --  | |       |    |      | (http://10.1.1.111) |
     |    |           | | |                | | |       |    |      |                     | 
user ----- ingress ---  | |      App       | | |-------------------       Database       |
     |    |           | | |________________| | |       |    |      |                     |
     |    |           |  ____________________  |       |    |      |_____________________|
     |    |            ________________________        |    |
     |    |____________________________________________|    |
      _______________________________________________________
```

If I use `eval $(minikube docker-env)` to go inside Kubernetes cluster and do `curl` command, it can connect to remote server:

```
      ------------------------------------------------------
     |   laptop                                             |
     |     ---------------- (Kubernetes) --------------     |     connect ok !
     |    |                                         * ----------------
     |    |            ------ deployment ------        |    |         |
     |    |           |  ------- pod --------  |       |    |       ---(remote server)---
     |    |           | |  -- contaniner --  | |       |    |      | (http://10.1.1.111) |
     |    |           | | |                | | |       |    |      |                     | 
user ----- ingress ---  | |      App       | | |-------------------       Database       |
     |    |           | | |________________| | |       |    |      |                     |
     |    |           |  ____________________  |       |    |      |_____________________|
     |    |            ________________________        |    |
     |    |____________________________________________|    |
      _______________________________________________________
```

and then I use `docker exec -it (docker id) /bin/bash` then do `curl`, it cannot connect to remote server:

```
      ------------------------------------------------------
     |   laptop                                             |
     |     ---------------- (Kubernetes) ---------------    |
     |    |                                            |    |   cannot connect !
     |    |            ------ deployment ------        |    |
     |    |           |  ------- pod --------  |       |    |       ---(remote server)---
     |    |           | |  -- contaniner --  | |       |    |      | (http://10.1.1.111) |
     |    |           | | |               *----------------------> |                     | 
user ----- ingress ---  | |      App       | | |-------------------       Database       |
     |    |           | | |________________| | |       |    |      |                     |
     |    |           |  ____________________  |       |    |      |_____________________|
     |    |            ________________________        |    |
     |    |____________________________________________|    |
      _______________________________________________________
```

The following is my configuration for Kubernetes:

ingress-service:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-service
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /?(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: qs-ts-cluster-ip-service
              servicePort: 8092
```

ip-service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: qs-ts-cluster-ip-service
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    component: qs-service-ts
  ports:
    - port: 8092
      targetPort: 8092
```

deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: qs-service-ts-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      component: qs-service-ts
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        component: qs-service-ts
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: qs-service-ts
          image: app/image
          command: ["sbt"]
          args: ["runMain com.app.http.appService"]
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8092
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: supersecret
```

Is there any good way I can connect to remote database from container in Kubernetes?

Comment: Can you try using the below commands
Get the pod list `kubectl get pods`
Go inside the container `kubectl exec -it pod-name bash` and try to run the curl command.

Comment: The `eval $(minikube ...)` command doesn't "go inside" anything; your second `curl` command is getting called from the same "laptop" box as the first one.  What sort of Kubernetes setup are you using (Docker Desktop, minikube, kind, ...)?  What error do you get?